# Load balancing using nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a machine with only nginx installed without passenger that acts as load balancer with ips of some machines in its upstream list. All the app machines have nginx with phusion passenger that serve the main application. Now some of the application machines are of medium type while others are large type. As far as I know the default nginx load balancing scheme is round robin. As the load is distributed among the large and medium machines equally, if the traffic is large the medium machines get overloaded and when its less the large machines resources are wasted. Now I use newrelic to monitor the cpu and memory on these machines and a script to get the data from newrelic, so is there any way to use this data to decide the traffic route on load balancer. 

One way I know is to monitor and the mark machines in upstream good or bad and then replace the upstream with the good ones and reload the nginx.conf each time without complete restart. So my second question, is the way correct. In other words does it have any drawbacks or will it cause any issues?

Third and more general question is there a better way tackle this issue of load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another load balancing algorithm that will distribute load more fair: http://nginx.org/r/least_conn or/and configure [weights](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server).

Making decision based on current cpu/memory usage isn't a good idea if your goal is faster request processing instead of meaningless numbers